# How to store two associated values as in array in Python

Tags: python, discord

I'm currently writing a bot for my discord that will have a levelling system. To do this, I have an array called "key", which stores the user IDs, and an array named "stats", which stores the user's levels.

I need to somehow merge these two arrays so that upon calling a userID, it has a specific level associated with it as well.

Comment: you want a `dict`

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested, use a [`Dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). If you insist on keeping those two in two separate lists, you can [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together and iterate over the result to get your `userID` <-> `level` pairs, but that's just wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment given by @juanpa.arrivallaga: you're looking for a "dictionary" data structure, rather than a pair of arrays. Instead of

```
key = ['user01', 'user02', ...]
stats = ['stat01', 'stat02', ...]
```

you want to make a dictionary, where each `key` is linked to the associated value in `stats`:

```
users = {'user01': 'stat01', 'user02': 'stat02', ...}
```

The way to do transmute the two lists into one dictionary is:

```
users = dict(zip(key, stats))
```

To elaborate: the function `zip()` is a built-in function that matches two same-size arrays together into a tuple:

```
zip(key, stats) == [('user01', 'stat01'), ('user02', 'stat02'), ...]
```

You could also use `zip()` for any number of iterable objects, and it would group them into tuples based on index.

The next part of the solution is simply to typecast that to `dict`, which is what python calls dictionaries. If you pass 2-tuples to `dict()`, python will automatically associate the first element (in this case, from `key`) as the key, and the second element (from `stats`) as the associated value.